# Implement MongoDB shell in GO

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have data in MongoDB as tree structure model. Here is my data structure:
[image]

Here is my Mongo shell to create collection:

```
db.users.insert({_id:"DHBK",username:"DHBK",password:"123456",lastname:"DHBK",user_email:"dhbk@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111001",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:null,com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"DHBK",user_code:"DHBK_0001",user_type:"ADMIN_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"KHOA_DIEN",username:"KHOA_DIEN",password:"123456",lastname:"KHOA_DIEN",user_email:"KHOA_DIEN@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111002",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"DHBK",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_DIEN",user_code:"DHBK_0002",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"KHOA_XD",username:"KHOA_XD",password:"123456",lastname:"KHOA_XD",user_email:"KHOA_XD@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111003",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"DHBK",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_XD",user_code:"DHBK_0003",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"KHOA_CNTT",username:"KHOA_CNTT",password:"123456",lastname:"KHOA_CNTT",user_email:"KHOA_CNTT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111004",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"DHBK",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_CNTT",user_code:"DHBK_0004",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"BOMON_TUDONG",username:"BOMON_TUDONG",password:"123456",lastname:"BOMON_TUDONG",user_email:"BOMON_TUDONG@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111005",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"KHOA_DIEN",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_DIEN",user_code:"DHBK_0005",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",username:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",password:"123456",lastname:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_email:"BOMON_VIENTHONG@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111006",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"KHOA_DIEN",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_DIEN",user_code:"DHBK_0006",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"BOMON_HETHONG",username:"BOMON_HETHONG",password:"123456",lastname:"BOMON_HETHONG",user_email:"BOMON_HETHONG@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111007",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"KHOA_DIEN",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_DIEN",user_code:"DHBK_0007",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"BOMON1_XD",username:"BOMON1_XD",password:"123456",lastname:"BOMON1_XD",user_email:"BOMON1_XD@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111008",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"KHOA_XD",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_XD",user_code:"DHBK_0008",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"BOMON2_XD",username:"BOMON2_XD",password:"123456",lastname:"BOMON2_XD",user_email:"BOMON2_XD@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111009",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"KHOA_XD",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_XD",user_code:"DHBK_0009",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"BOMON3_XD",username:"BOMON3_XD",password:"123456",lastname:"BOMON3_XD",user_email:"BOMON3_XD@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111010",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"KHOA_XD",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"KHOA_XD",user_code:"DHBK_0010",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"TRUONGKHOA_BMVT",username:"TRUONGKHOA_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"TRUONGKHOA_BMVT",user_email:"TRUONGKHOA_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111011",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0011",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"PHOKHOA_BMVT",username:"PHOKHOA_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"PHOKHOA_BMVT",user_email:"PHOKHOA_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111012",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0012",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"THUKY_BMVT",username:"THUKY_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"THUKY_BMVT",user_email:"THUKY_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111013",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0013",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"GV_BMVT",username:"GV_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"GV_BMVT",user_email:"GV_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111014",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0014",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"SV1_BMVT",username:"SV1_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"SV1_BMVT",user_email:"SV1_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111015",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"GV_BMVT",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0015",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"SV2_BMVT",username:"SV2_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"SV2_BMVT",user_email:"SV2_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111016",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"GV_BMVT",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0016",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"SV3_BMVT",username:"SV3_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"SV3_BMVT",user_email:"SV3_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111017",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"GV_BMVT",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0017",user_type:"USER_COM"});
db.users.insert({_id:"SV4_BMVT",username:"SV4_BMVT",password:"123456",lastname:"SV4_BMVT",user_email:"SV4_BMVT@edu.com.vn",user_tel:"0907111018",user_date:"2020-05-05",user_status:"ACTIVE",user_parentid:"GV_BMVT",com_id:"DHBK",com_department:"BOMON_VIENTHONG",user_code:"DHBK_0018",user_type:"USER_COM"});
```

In my practices, I want to remove Node parent means delete all Node Descendants.

For example:

When I remove " BOMON_VIENTHONG " node, it must remove TRUONGKHOA_BMVT, PHOKHOA_BMVT, THUKY_BMVT , GV_BMVT, SV1_BMVT, SV2_BMVT, SV3_BMVT, SV4_BMVT.

I can use Mongo shell to execute this remove action. Here is my Mongo shell

```
TOP_LEVEL_PARENT = "BOMON_VIENTHONG"
db.users.aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
      from: "users",
      startWith: "$user_parentid",
      connectFromField: "user_parentid",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "hierarchy"
      }
   },
  { 
  $match: { 
      $or: [ 
         { "hierarchy._id":  TOP_LEVEL_PARENT },
         { _id: TOP_LEVEL_PARENT }
          ]
      } 
  }
] 
).forEach( doc => db.users.deleteOne( { _id: doc._id } ) )
```

I want implement this Mongo shell in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working Golang code, you just need to **update MongoDB connection string and database name**.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb_connect_string"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    database := client.Database("testdb")
    users := database.Collection("users")

    matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"$or", bson.A{bson.D{{"_id", "BOMON_VIENTHONG"}}, bson.D{{"hierarchy._id", "BOMON_VIENTHONG"}}}}}}}
    graphStage := bson.D{{"$graphLookup", bson.D{{"from", "users"}, {"startWith", "$user_parentid"}, {"connectFromField", "user_parentid"}, {"connectToField", "_id"}, {"as", "hierarchy"} }}}

    showInfoCursor, err := users.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{graphStage, matchStage})
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    var showsWithInfo []bson.M
    if err = showInfoCursor.All(ctx, &showsWithInfo); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    for _, doc := range showsWithInfo {
        _, err := users.DeleteOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": doc["_id"]})
        if (err != nil) {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, can you use in mgo, please?

Comment: It's work for me, but I am using mgo in function connection, insert, update,...